# "No provisioning iOS device connected"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

About 3 months ago I set up my iPhone for development; installed the provisioning profile, updated the device to the latest version of iOS, namely 4.3.3 (8J2) and testing applications on my iPhone worked 100%.

Today I went back to working on one of my iPhone applications after not having worked in XCode for about a month, and now I do not seem to be able to deploy applications to my iPhone. When I try deploy and run on my iPhone, I get the message "No provisioning iOS device connected", even though my iPhone is connected.

If I look in the organizer window of XCode, I see my iPhone listed there under DEVICES, but I see the following message when I select my iPhone entry:

```
The version of iOS on “Bruce Hill’s iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS 
supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the 
device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS 
SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Bruce Hill’s iPhone
4.3.3 (8J2)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
4.3.3 (8J2)
4.2 (8C134)
4.1
4.0
4.0.2
4.0.1
3.2
3.2.2
3.2.1
3.1
3.1.3
3.1.2
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here and why XCode seems to think that my iPhone has an unsupported version of iOS installed, when in fact the latest version is installed?

UPDATE:

I have tried restarting my Macbook Pro, doing a hard reboot of my iPhone and removing my iphone entry in the organizer. None of these actions helped. My iPhone keeps getting listed in the organizer with an orange circle and if I hover over my iPhone entry I get a tooltip message that says "This device is busy or otherwise unusable by Xcode."

I did notice that in my developer information in System Profiler it only shows sdk 4.2 (8C134) installed, not 4.3.3 (8J2), even though Xcode lists it as being present and supported in the message I quoted above. Here is my developer information:

```
Version:    3.2 (10M2423)
Location:   /Developer
Applications:
Xcode:  3.2.5 (1760)
Interface Builder:  3.2.5 (823)
Instruments:    2.7 (3017)
Dashcode:   3.0.2 (333)
SDKs:
Mac OS X:
10.4:   (8S2167)
10.5:   (9L31a)
10.6:   (10M2423)
iPhone OS:
4.2:    (8C134)
iPhone Simulator:
3.2:    (7W367a)
4.0:    (8A400)
4.1:    (8B117)
4.2:    (8C134)
```

Comment: You may be compiling against the wrong version of the sdk, you may want to check that.  It would help if you mentioned which version of xcode you are using.

Comment: Hi James. My xcode version is 3.2.5 64-bit. The component version are as follows... 
Xcode IDE: 1760.0
Xcode Core: 1763.0
ToolSupport: 1758.0
I think you may be right about the sdk version, I am going to check that out.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode, your device, etc.?

Comment: I think you might have updated your iOS device to the latest version since the last you hooked the device to Xcode.  When you start Xcode, it will ask to collect some info.  I just clicked ok...it happened to mine but I just could remember the exact message.  But it is very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened here is that I installed Xcode and then later did an update of my iPhone to iOS 4.3.3. This problem then occurred because my Macbook Pro actually didn't have the SDK for 4.3 installed, even though Xcode seemed to think that it was installed.

So, I got this working by downloading an installing Xcode 4.0.2 and iOS SDK 4.3. I downloaded Xcode from here: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Once Xcode 4.0.2 was installed and running, I connected my iPhone, it showed the orange dot again briefly (for about 10 seconds or so) and then this turned to a green dot and I was able to deploy my application to my device again... FINALLY!! :) In my developer settings in System Profiler, I also see iPhone OS: 4.3:(8H7) listed there now. I think that this issue would also have been resolved by installing Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3, as this would, I think, also have resolved the missing or corrupt SDK 4.3 on my Macbook, but I chose to download and install the latest version.

So, bottom line: Xcode working again! I am happy! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my 3GS and i solve it by resetting iPhone's developer configuration. Try to hard reset your device ([here' the link](http://www.wikihow.com/Hard-Reset-an-iPhone&ved=0CBIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFhRPia9en4yjNVFaQnXSC8gTM_9g) - don't worry, your dta will survive). Then remove your device from Xcode organizer and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Also try 'Cleaning' your Xcode project and just turning off your phone and back on again. Restart your computer while you're at it. After it's back up, open Xcode, then plug in the device. It should do its thing then start working again. I had the same issue a few times when I updated and hadn't disconnected/reconnected everything.